# How can I pass properties of parent component to a child component without explicitly naming them?

Tags: ember.js

Let's assume there is a parent component A, which has a child component B, which in turn has a sub child C.

```
// Template A 
{{B param1=1 param2=2 param3=3 ....}}

// Template B
{{C param1=param1 param2=param2 param3=param3 ....}}
```

Template C will list all the params sent to it. There is no fixed length or name for the params.

My objective is (from B) is to receive params from A and send all of them into C. How could I obtain the list of params and send them to child with binding intact with A ?

Comment: please check my answer and ping me if you need more help in understanding it; I might prepare a twiddle for you if needed when I have time. I simply like the power of `yield` :) and this is an excellent case to show it in action.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you will see this as an answer; but what I do when I encounter requirements such as yours is to only pass the parameters to component `C`. This is only possible via yielding. So; what I suggest is just do not render `C` within `B` and `yield` `C` to be rendered within `A`. Here is a snippet of what I mean:

```
{{!-- Template for B --}}
{{yield (hash c=(component 'C-component'))}}

{{!-- Template for A --}}
{{#B-component as |b|}}
    {{b.c param1=param1 param2=param2}}
{{/B-component}}
```

This might seem weird at first sight; however this is the beauty of Ember's contextual components. If `B` does nothing with the parameters passed to it and it is just passing them to `C`; why bother `B` with those parameters at the first place and break its API. It simply does not need those params; hence they should be passed directly to `C` thanks to yielding.